# Play Store Beta version visible to non-testers

Tags: google-play

I was under the impression that Applications in the Google Play Store that were in Beta and not in production would be visible only to a small group of users.  I have some evidence that that is not the case.

I've got an app that for a few months I've been distributing privately to a group of beta testers.  The first thing the app does is to request an email address so that I can communicate with the user.  It sends me a message via HTTP POST with the entered email address, as well as version info and some characterisics of the user's hardware.

Two days ago I moved it to the Play Store as a Beta.  I chose a package name different from the privately distributed version.  I've gone through all the steps of creating a Google+ community, following the testing link, opting in as a tester, and downloading the Beta app to my phone.

The only members of the Google+ group at this time are myself and one friend.  I haven't publicized the Play Store app to anyone.  There is no production version.

I just got a message via HTTP POST message that a new user was using the .apk that I posted to the store as a beta.  I responded by sending an email to the address that was presented, asking how they were able to download it.  If I get a reply (which I doubt will happen) I'll post it here.

How is this possible?  Perhaps there's a hole in Google's security?

I was planning on distributing a free app that is fully functional for 7 days, then requires an in-app purchase for continued use.  The beta version would be fully functional at all times, but distribution would be limited to the few people I approve.  Is there a major security risk that unauthorized people might help themselves to a free app?

Comment: I just got a second beta registration.  Both times it's happened, it's been a few minutes after my uploading a new version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both "registrations" both came a few minutes after I uploaded a new APK to the Play Store.
2. Both registrations were made using similar Google Nexus 5 devices.

The evidence is circumstantial, but my best guess now is that there must be somebody at Google whose job it is to test newly uploaded software and make sure it doesn't violate any of their rules.

It's not a bug, it's a feature!